# Unity Firebase Database working only in editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I have a piece of code that saves my ussers in my database like so:

```
public void createAccount()
{
    FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("https://xxx-xxx.firebaseio.com/");
    FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorP12FileName("xxx xxx-dd21907c659a.p12");
    FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorServiceAccountEmail("xxx@xxx-xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com");
    FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorP12Password("notasecret"); 

    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;

    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("users").Child(username.GetComponent<InputField>().text).Child("likes").GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => 
    {
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            email.GetComponent<InputField>().textComponent.color = Color.red;
        }
        else if (task.IsCompleted)
        {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;

            if (snapshot.Value == null)
            {
                DataBase.userID = username.GetComponent<InputField>().text;
                DataBase.email = email.GetComponent<InputField>().text;
                DataBase.password = password.GetComponent<InputField>().text;
                DataBase.signedIn = true;

                reference.Child("users").Child(DataBase.userID).Child("likes").SetValueAsync(DataBase.followers);
                reference.Child("users").Child(DataBase.userID).Child("email").SetValueAsync(DataBase.email);
                reference.Child("users").Child(DataBase.userID).Child("password").SetValueAsync(DataBase.password);

                SceneManager.LoadScene("game");
            }
            else
            {
                username.GetComponent<InputField>().textComponent.color = Color.red;
            }
        }
    });

}
```

It works just fine when I use it on unity but when I compile it and run it on my android device it doesn't send any information to the database. It does not even turn the text color to red which would indicate that the task is faulted.... Hope you can help me figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove spaces from the project direction, including the name itself.
try to make the names of all the directories in the project space-free.